# Intermittent `NetworkError` response server side s3.upload

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-nodejs

I'm using `s3.upload` on the AWS Node.js SDK to upload photos on the server side.

I've noticed that since yesterday, AWS has been returning `NetworkError`'s intermittently.

It's really strange, it only seems to be happening on Vercel's API routes.

When I run the same code as a CLI command, the uploads work fine. When I use a different Lambda based environment, no issue.

CORS doesn't apply, since this is a purely server to server upload, but I have enabled CORS just to be sure.

Only on Vercel hosting do I see this issue, at the moment. I'm trying to make sure it's not an AWS SDK version issue too.

Here's the `err` data from the `upload` callback:

```
              "data": {
                "errorMessage": "NetworkingError [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client",
                "errorType": "Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection",
                "reason": {
                  "code": "NetworkingError",
                  "errorMessage": "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client",
                  "errorType": "NetworkingError",
                  "hostname": "bucket.s3.amazonaws.com",
                  "message": "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client",
                  "region": "us-east-1",
                  "retryable": true,
                  "stack": [
                    "Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client",
                    "    at new NodeError (internal/errors.js:322:7)",
                    "    at ClientRequest.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:561:11)",
                    "    at Object.mod.request (/var/task/___vc/__launcher.js:90:17)",
                    "    at features.constructor.handleRequest (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/http/node.js:45:23)",
                    "    at executeSend (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:452:29)",
                    "    at Request.SEND (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:466:9)",
                    "    at Request.callListeners (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:102:18)",
                    "    at Request.emit (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)",
                    "    at Request.emit (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:686:14)",
                    "    at Request.transition (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)"
                  ],
                  "time": "2023-04-27T11:03:16.773Z"
                },
                "stack": [
                  "Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection: NetworkingError [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client",
                  "    at process.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:35:15)",
                  "    at process.emit (events.js:412:35)",
                  "    at process.emit (domain.js:475:12)",
                  "    at processPromiseRejections (internal/process/promises.js:245:33)",
                  "    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:96:32)"
                ]
              }
```

Answer (score 0):

It was Vercel after all.

Here's a thread of others with the same issue overnight:

https://github.com/orgs/vercel/discussions/2204